# Wi-Fi starts only after Suspend (in Ubuntu) and Sleep or Hibernate (in Windows)

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, suspend, hibernate

So, I had dual boot - Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1. The Wi-Fi worked well and good. Everything worked perfectly but then I had some problem with the hinge of my laptop and also the LCD so I had to give my laptop to a local repair shop for few hours. Then the hinge and the LCD problem was fixed but the Wi-Fi stopped working.

**In Windows** - I was unable to turn on the Wi-Fi, it was disabled, I couldn't enable the Wi-Fi and the enable option was greyed out. After troubleshooting it would say ***Wireless Capability is turned off***. I pressed Fn + F12 but nothing would happen. But the Wi-Fi would start on its own automatically after few hours (sometimes 1 hour, sometimes 2 hours or more) without me doing anything. 
Then I replaced the HDD with one having Windows 7 installed. It worked properly over there with no problem at all. In win 8.1, I updated all the drivers, scanned for hardware changes (there was no hardware changes), I upgraded to Windows 10, nothing happened. But then I discovered, once I shutdown my PC and then boot it, the Wi-Fi was disabled but then i put it on Sleep or Hibernate it and then if i start it again, the Wi-Fi worked.

**In Ubuntu** - It said ***Wi-Fi is disabled by hardware switch***. I opened up the backcover thinking some wired connection was done properly but everything was fine. I did the same, Fn + F12, sudo rfkill, but nothing happened. The wifi would not start, in both Windows and Ubuntu, the Ethernet cable worked just fine. But then also in Ubuntu I discovered, that after i boot to Ubuntu and then i put it on suspend and then again start ubuntu, the Wi-Fi would start working.

In both the cases the Wi-Fi doesn't work on boot but after Suspend/Sleep, it starts working. There was no such problem before I gave it for repairing. What is causing this issue?

Comment: Maybe they resetted the BIOS at the shop. Check that all the devices in the BIOS are not hardware-disabled or don't have weird settings; which options to check is strictly hardware-dependent, you should refer to your laptop's user guide for instructions on how boot into the BIOS and for directions on which sections to look up for.

Comment: @kos there is no network option in the BIOS and neither is there any network in the windows mobility center.

Comment: I have the same problem on an HP Pavilion dv6 laptop using the Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 wifi. I swapped it out thinking it may be the problem for a Broadcom 4313 but still have the issue. For now, I just close the lid and suspend the laptop, open it again an the wifi is working. Strange. I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 with no improvement.